# My Dialoglfow chatbot reply time from the bot is very low. How to rectify it?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have built a dialoglow chatbot and integrated with website.
It is working fine.
But the reply time from the bot is too slow, which can create a bad user experience.
What can I do to solve this.
Thanks,

I have tried integrating again, but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any fulfillment (ie. making dialogflow to interact with a backend API to find answers)?

If not, I recommend you testing the chatbot interaction using the bot console. If it is fast, maybe the culprit may be on your frontend code.

Comment: Yes, I am using fulfillment.
I am using the API to store the data gathered during the chatbot interaction with the user.